# How to make the flutter audioplayer automatically change from speaker to headphones when user attaches headphones / airpods?

Tags: flutter-audioplayers

I am instantiating a flutter audioplayers instance like this:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(DeviceFileSource(widget.recording.localFilePath!));
```

This works fine in the app, but it won't play through the headphones and I don't see anything in the docs. All I found was this: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/pull/515